# getting the return value of a command using ACE in c++

Tags: c++, ace

I need to run a shell command on Linux from within a c++ process and get its return value.
Is there a way doing it with ACE?
I know that in c++ I can use popen. I am looking for an ACE solution.

Comment: This [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) or some other one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ACE is [Adaptive Communication Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Communication_Environment), it looks like you need to call `ACE_Process::return_value`. [ACE_Process doc](http://doxygen.theaceorb.nl/libace-doc/a00497.html#aea62a07365725dc5e22f29e48bb74290).